# Can SSIS package ran but not deployed affect server?

Tags: database, ssis, etl

I am a SSIS New Bee. I adjust a SSIS package. Ran it. All green. Then I thought I deployed to the server database. And that day when I queried the database ,it showed the new result instead of old version.
But 2 days later the other team told me I didn't deployed. Then I checked deployed history it didn't show.

I ran the package for sure, queried out the new set for sure. But because of this version thing. I am not very so sure if I deployed that day.

Could a SSIS ran and changed the server database without deployment?

PS the server database I deployed is the "Develop" environment.

Check the version history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could a SSIS ran and changed the server database without deployment?

Yes, running the package has nothing to do with deployment. Successful run will affect the server regardless of whether it was run locally or after deployment.

Deployment is just a way to store package in SQL server, and optionally automate running it there. But it is completely optional.

Answer (score 0):

If your Data Flows were connected to the database, yes the database will be affected by whatever operations the package ran, regardless of deployment.

The deployment of a package only affects if it will be shown in the SSIS Catalog on that particular SQL Server.

Simply running the package in SSIS (all green) does NOT update the package's version in SQL Server. You need to deploy for that.